# Make php explode split sentence into words

Tags: php, explode

I may be misunderstanding the documentation, but when I code

```
explode(" ","here's a sentence",2 )
```

I end up with...

```
Array
(
    [0] => here's
    [1] => a sentence with a few words in it
)
```

Is there a way to make explode return...

```
Array
(
    [0] => here's
    [1] => a
)
```

I'm trying to make it take the first two words of any string it's given and put them into an array.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
$result = array_slice(explode(" ","here's a sentence", 3), 0, 2);
```